# How to use VOIP for voice calling in Android like Skype and Viber

Tags: android, voip

I am developing an Android App in which i have to use voice calling using internet to all mobile app like Skype and Viber.
i think i will have to use VOIP of that functionality. is there any one worked on that or anyone can suggest me batter link for that.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio is a best-documented and famous solution as for me..

https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/android

You can make your app call either to other devices or to usual numbers. It provides great possibilities.

Comment: i have completely read it and configured it but i couldn't get success